# Can I refresh `node_modules` without restarting my nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, npm, updates

Is that possible to refresh some dependencies when a node.js application is running ?

For instance, I'm using a specific version of `lodash`, a new version is released, can I trigger the refresh directly from my app, or I'll add necessariliy to edit `package.json` and rebuild the app manually?

Answer (score 5):

Just to get a few facts straight:

1. Once a module is loaded, the operative code lives in memory in the JS interpreter.  Changing the file on disk has no affect at all.
2. Once a module is loaded and other modules have a reference to it, there is no systematic way to replace that module reference with a new one.  You could conceivably delete the prior module from the module cache, load a new module, get a new module handle and manually tell every piece of code that was using the prior module that they should switch over to using the new module handle, but that's a lot of custom code and there are likely some caveats to making that work properly in some circumstances.
3. node.js does not have any built-in way to replace code with a new version of the code.
4. The usual way to "upgrade" your code is to replace the code with the updated code and then restart your app so it will load the new version of the code.

> Is that possible to refresh some dependencies when a node.js application is running ?

So, it is technically feasible to manually delete a module from the module cache, then manually load an update version of the module and then manually tell everyone who was using the old module handle that they should switch over to the new module handle.  But, this all assumes that there's no state in the original module that needs to be preserved and assumes that you have some way of giving every user of the module a new module handle.  It's a big hand coded project with a lot of limitations (e.g. only works in very limited circumstances).

> For instance, I'm using a specific version of lodash, a new version is released, can I trigger the refresh directly from my app or I'll add necessariliy to edit package.json and rebuild the app manually?

Replace code with updated code, restart your app.  That's the usual way.